# How to make json output to normal output in streamlit?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, set, streamlit

I have a code which gives output like below

```
{
"Pdf":"July 20.pdf"
"Content":"Include any error messages"
"Page no":6
}
{
"Pdf":"July 20, 2016.pdf"
"Content":"Show what you’ve tried and tell us"
"Page no":7
}
```

But i need output like

```
"Pdf":"July 20.pdf", "Content":"Include any error messages", "Page no":6
"Pdf":"July 20, 2016.pdf", "Content":"Show what you’ve tried and tell us", "Page no":7
```

I'm working on streamlit. Below is the code

```
results = search(query, top_k=2, index=index, model=search_model)
for result in results:
    st.write(result)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print it as a string and replace some chars.

#### Code

```
results = [
{
"Pdf":"July 20.pdf",
"Content":"Include any error messages",
"Page no":6
},
{
"Pdf":"July 20, 2016.pdf",
"Content":"Show what you’ve tried and tell us",
"Page no":7
}
]


for result in results:
    st.write(str(result).replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('\'', '\"'))
```

#### Output

```
"Pdf": "July 20.pdf", "Content": "Include any error messages", "Page no": 6

"Pdf": "July 20, 2016.pdf", "Content": "Show what you’ve tried and tell us", "Page no": 7
```